# Android Studio 2.2 Stuck at Building Gradle Project Info on importing existing project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I am using Android studio 2.2 on windows 10.

I am trying to import an existing android project. The problem that it took forever and still showing the message

> Building 'ProjecTName' Graedle project info

after that android studio is totally getting stuck and i kill it from the task manager !

I tried the available options on Android Studio list:

1. Open an existing Android Studio Project
2. Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)

[image: test]

Comment: Same configuration on my system, didn't get such issue yet. did you retried.

Comment: of course for many times, Android studio then totally stuck and i needed to  kill it from the task manager. @lRadha

Comment: The problem is probably with the gradle distribution download or dependencies resolve. Check if any network proxy is set on your os or IDE

Comment: i dont have any problem with the network, i made sure that internet connection is working and there is not proxy @FarhadFaghihi

Comment: is that an Android studio code or Eclipse

Comment: android studio code with gradle in it. @lRadha

Comment: then import it as android project, the first option. (And also make sure that all the applications burning CPU must be closed first.) If it did not work just remove the gradle files and import it as Eclipse, ADT project

Comment: @lRadha i wrote in the question that i have tried both options and same result

Comment: just remove gradle files from the project folder and try again

Comment: @lRadha Yes that was it ! i removed the gradle, i copy and pasted it from another project, it worked now ! Thank you

Comment: @lRadha please add it as answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had deleted all gradle folder and copied it from another project and pasted it, this worked for me

Comment: Why did you then marked yours as the right if @lRadha has answered first?

Answer (score 32):

There is downloading of Gradle going on at the background. Just wait for it to finish.

Comment: looks so stupid but ...... very true ..you can check in network operations in background for android studio :-D

Comment: Took a couple of minutes for me to progress past this step.

Comment: I waited more than half an hour once. But it doesn't look like always it is network problem.

Comment: Same here. It took 3 to 4 minutes. Just wait for it.

Comment: That seems to be the case, we should get informed of the operation somehow though...

Comment: A definite progress bar and a progress message wouldn't hurt. But Google..........

Answer (score 21):

Just Remove Gradle files from your project folder and retry.

Hope this will help.

Comment: it worked ... i deleted all gradle folder and copied it from another project and pasted it, this worked for me

Comment: @MBH  yes, as you said I just replaced that 'gradle' folder with one of a project I worked on recently.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the problem.

I downloaded the gradle 3.5 binary distribution zip file, deleted the gradle folder from my project, then went to settings of Android Studio, checked "Offline work", used "Use local gradle distribution" and set the path of unzipped gradle folder
on the "Gradle home" and "Service directory path" text fields.

Then I tried to open the project with Android Studio 2.3.

Then a message is shown and I pressed cancel to manually configure the gradle, then I located the unzipped gradle folder again. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

1> Try Removing(Deleting) the gradle files from the project folder and then re-try.

2> Try to go into the android studio and then Files>Invalidate Caches/Restart and then try.

3> If the above two don't work do check the gradle,android Studio versions and see if those need updating.

4> Above 3 usually work for me , if it still persists, then you need to check the dependencies for the project. Also try importing some other project and if the same issue occurs, try a new installation of a **STABLE version** of the android studio.

Comment: the first option which worked for me, i already use Android studio 2.2 which is **STABLE version** .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove C:\Users\User.gradle

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. The actual path is c:\users\[username]\.gradle I ran a couplel of react-native projects before

Answer (score 2):

The above answers didn't work for me well.

I have several projects with different gradle versions, and whenever I tried to open a project the Android Studio started downloading its gradle in the background.

So, things to do before importing old projects to new Android Studio / Gradle.

1. In file 'build.gradle' replace old line with    "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'"
   (Assuming 2.3.3 is the latest. You can check this in your newly/recently created project)
2. In file 'gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties' replace old line with 'distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'
   (Assuming 3.3 is the latest. You can check this in your newly/recently created project)

Now when you'll import, it wont download other gradle version.

I did find-replace for the above lines in my whole directory containing all my old projects, using Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the real Problem is that the studio is downloading gradle files throught internet and sometimes it is not able to do so, then it stucks but we can manually fix it through-

Download Gradle Files according to your android Studios version.

You can download gradle files through-https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

See your Gradle vesrion through-https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html in the Update Gradle area.

Download the Gradle and paste it into- c:/Users/username/local/.gradle

and this is It!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found that my gradle files had the gradle version set 2.1.0. So I opened the files in wordpad and first changed that to 3.3 And then it worked fine for me.

And in the gradel-wrapper.properties:
From `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
To `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`
Hope that will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.. Will work for you for sure.

step 1: Delete "only" the Gradle "folder" from your project folder.

step 2: Import your project from Android Studio & a dialog box will appear "press 
        Ok to use..., or Cancel to... ". Press "Cancel" & locate the path where you have downloaded the latest Gradle File (C:/Gradle/gradle-3.5  ,in my case).

Step 3: it will give an error saying that "no cache version for....". So now check which version of com.android.tools.build:gradle: you have.. so check the path "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle" and select the latest version (2.3.2 in my case). So now, go to Gradle Scripts-> build.gradle(android) in Android Studio and change the dependencie's classpath to (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2')in my case

step 4: Click on "try again". Then it'll ask for upgrading tools, upgrade it by clicking on it & then you're done..

Congrats, your Project is successfully built..

And yeah make sure that In Setting-> Build,Exec...->Gradle-> "check mark on Use local gradle distribution & offline work &  Gradle home: C:/Gradle/gradle-3.5  & Service directory path: C:/Gradle/gradle-3.5 (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting temp and temp% worked for me!

Comment: from where exactly ?

Comment: Windows + R, type in temp or %temp%

Comment: I am a Mac user :( Thanks for sharing

Comment: @MBH Really? Your screenshots are of Windows 10

Comment: @nmnsud everyone wanted to be a mac user coz of price!

Answer (score 0):

Download  manually [gradle-3.3-all.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip)

and extract into `/Users/[yourUsername]/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/`